# Complex type inside custom control in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, custom-controls

How can I setup a complex property inside a custom control, I have tried the following. The problem is that I can't access the complex property inside the custom control class.

Example custom control code:

```
public class MyCustomControl : Control, IStylesheet
{
        [
            Bindable(true),
            Category("Appearance"),
            DefaultValue(""),
            Description("FullName"),
            DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content),
            PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty),
        ]
        public FullName MyFullName {get; set;}

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            // I want to access MyFullName from .aspx here
        }
}

public class FullName
{
    public string Firstname {get; set;}
    public string Lastname {get; set;}
}
```

.aspx markup

```
<Namespace:MyCustomControl runat="server"">
    <MyFullName Firstname="abc" Lastname="def" /> 
</Namespace:MyCustomControl>
```

Comment: What do you mean by " I can't access the complex property inside the custom control class"?  Why can't you do this.MyFullName??  I have a property with [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content), MergableProperty(false), PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)] defined, and I can access it fine...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are not able to get the values of FirstName/lastname property that is set in the markup from inside the render method of the custom control.

Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s70936s.aspx) article. Excerpts from the article, applied to your situation are below.

The MyFullName property and the properties of the MyFullName class need design-time attributes to enable persistence within the control's tags, as shown in the following example:

```
 <aspSample:MyCustomControl >
      <MyFullName FirstName="Jody" LastName="Foster" />
    </aspSample:MyCustomControl>
```

The MyCustomControl control stores its simple properties in the ViewState dictionary. However, the MyCustomControl control has to implement custom state management for the FullName property to manage the state of the property across postbacks.